# the names on x-label in the histogram are cut out

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a histogram which counts the frequency of the occurrence of the labels.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#upload dataset
train_data_fig = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\liar-dataset\\train.csv')


#make the histogram
plt.hist(train_data_fig['PARTY-AFFILIATION'].astype(str), bins=100, align='mid')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('speaker-state-info')
plt.show()
```

The output is the following histogram:

[image]

As we can see, the x-label names are cut out. Is there a way I can make the labels visible or decrease the font-size.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider trying the easy potential fix before anything more involved: `plt.tight_layout()`. Reference: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html

Comment: I fixed it by using plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5).